# Problem to detect already purchased products (Inapp iphone sdk)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I'm trying to add Inapp products on my app.

1. I can list the inapp products that I created.
2. I can show the payment popup and I can buy the product without problems.

But... I can't verify if this device have already purchased this product, when I launch the app.

I'm using MKStore class, this have a function to verify if the product has been already purchased:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Myproduct1"]){
           NSLog(@"Already Purchased");
}
```

But I always receive false.

If I open the app, and I press the button to bought again this product , I receive an alert like "You already bought this product, press OK to download it.".

The payment were did okay, but I don't know how verify it... I want to disable the "pay" button on products that has been purchased when the app starts.

**EDIT:**

solved! But... if I uninstall the app, the standardUserDefaults are restarted and I don't know which products has been purchased... There is some method to ask Apple, if the product is already bought?

Comment: Have you actually done `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Myproduct1"]` ?

Comment: Error: "void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Comment: That's not an answer to my question, is it ?

Comment: I had not understood you, this was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you haven't actually set the user default key.

When you've completed your purchase, you need to set the corresponding key in your user defaults, like this:

```
- (void)product1WasPurchased
{
    // Remember that product 1 was purchased.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Myproduct1"];
    // If you want to be sure that the preferences are saved immediately
    // you need to call:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // Do some other stuff.
    ...
}
```

Only after you have actually set the bool your check can succeed:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Myproduct1"]){
    NSLog(@"Already Purchased");
}
```

Comment: Okay, solved! But... if I uninstall the app, the standardUserDefaults are restarted and I don't know which products has been purchased... There is some method to ask Apple, if the product is already bought?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to do this would be to send the receipt object to your server, and store it in a database.

That way, you can manage purchases, at least on a device-by-device basis, and you get the added benefit of being able to verify your purchase receipt with Apple outside of your app code, where it can't be hacked as easily.

Downside is you have to maintain a server and webservice and your app needs an internet connection to verify its' purchases.